# Getting the argument types of a constructor using Data and Typeable

Tags: haskell, reflection, types, generic-programming

I'm playing around with Haskell's [Data](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-Data.html) and [Typeable](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Typeable.html), and I'm stuck trying to get the arguments of a function without a type variable being available in the context.

Let me clarify what I mean. As long as I have the type variable `a` quantified like below, I can use `fromConstr` and obtain a list of `DataType` or `TypeRep` as I wish:

```hs
constrArgs :: forall a. Data a => Constr -> [DataType]
constrArgs c = gmapQ f (fromConstr c :: a)
  where f :: forall d. Data d => d -> DataType
        f _ = dataTypeOf @d undefined
```

(I realize the `undefined` and `fromConstr` are nontotal but laziness saves us here.)

However, if I try to avoid quantifying `a`, I can no longer do a type ascription to the result of `fromConstr`. I wonder if there is a way to write a function with the following type signature:

```hs
constrArgs' :: Constr -> [DataType]
```

My end goal is to write a function that gives a list of lists of `DataType`s, a sublist for each constructor, each sublist containing the argument types of that constructor. Using the first version, it's not difficult to write a function with the type signature: (definition elided)

```hs
allConstrArgs :: forall a. Data a => [[DataType]]
```

The problem with this is that I cannot apply `allConstrArgs` to the results of itself, because there is no way to go from `DataType` to a type-level value.

So, in order to amend that, can we write a function that has the following type?

```hs
allConstrsArgs' :: DataType -> [[DataType]]
```

I looked around in the base library but I'm failing to see how this can be achieved.

Comment: The problem is that `Constr` by itself just doesn't have enough data inside. The types of arguments are all hidden within `gmapQ`. `Constr` is just a bunch of string names, [take a look at its source](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/Data.Data.html#Constr). And same applies to `DataType`.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin It's really not that helpful to say "look, here's the source, it just doesn't work." That frames it as a inexplicable bug when it's a design choice. @OP The principle of `Data` is that you operate on *values*. The facilities for inspecting the abstract structure of a type are not present in `Data`; that's not what it is for. `Data` is for walking the concrete structure of a value and its subvalues. You can't peek at a constructor's fields without having values for them, and using `undefined` is a brute-force band-aid. The correct tool to abstractly analyze a type is `Generic`.

Comment: @HTNW I'm fine with bruce-force band-aids as long as the clients of my functions don't see how it's implemented or don't get runtime errors.
I want to avoid `Generic` because type-level hackery has problems of its own. See the accepted answer for how to use `Data` for this.

Comment: @JoomyKorkut Well, now I'm interested. What's goes wrong with `Generic`?

Comment: @HTNW I can't go into full detail here but for what I want to do, I'd need to have separate type class instances for `D1`,`C1`,`S1`,`U1`,`V1`,`:+:`,`:*:`,`Rec0` etc. I can go deep into the shape of an ADT, but I lose the big picture, keeping track of the initial point is more difficult, checking if a type is recursive or if it's mutually recursive via `Generic` is more difficult than it is with `Data` and `Typeable`. Not to mention that I'd have to do it in type-level instead of value-level. Harder to understand and harder to present in a paper.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't get a list of argument types out of a `Constr`, because it just doesn't have enough data in it: it's a bunch of strings, nothing more.

However, there is a way to achieve your bigger goal: you just need to carry the `Data` dictionary around with you, and what better way to do it than an existential type!

```
data D = forall a. Data a => D a

allConstrArgs :: D -> [[D]]
allConstrArgs d = constrArgs d <$> allConstrs d

constrArgs :: D -> Constr -> [D]
constrArgs (D a) c = gmapQ D $ mkConstr a c
    where
        mkConstr :: forall a. Data a => a -> Constr -> a
        mkConstr _ = fromConstr

allConstrs :: D -> [Constr]
allConstrs (D a) = case dataTypeRep $ dataTypeOf a of
    AlgRep constrs -> constrs
    _ -> []

mkD :: forall a. Data a => D
mkD = D (undefined :: a)
```

Here the type `D` serves solely to wrap the `Data` dictionary - the actual value `a` will always be `undefined`, and never actually evaluated, so that's fine. The value `D` thus serves as a value-level representation of a type, such that upon destructuring you get a `Data` instance for that type in scope.

The function `constrArgs` takes a type representation `D` and a constructor `Constr`, and returns a list of that constructor's parameters, each represented as `D` as well - so now you can feed its output back into its input! It does this by using `gmapQ`, whose first argument type perfectly fits the `D` constructor.

`mkD` is just a utility function meant to hide the unpleasantness of `undefined` and to be used with `TypeApplications`, e.g. `mkD @Int`.

And here's usage:

```
data X = X0 Int | X1 String deriving (Typeable, Data)
data Y = Y0 String | Y1 Bool | Y2 Char deriving (Typeable, Data)
data Z = ZX X | ZY Y deriving (Typeable, Data)

typName :: D -> String
typName (D a) = dataTypeName $ dataTypeOf a

main = do
    -- Will print [["Prelude.Int"],["Prelude.[]"]]
    print $ map typName <$> allConstrArgs (mkD @X)

    -- Will print [["Prelude.[]"],["Bool"],["Prelude.Char"]]
    print $ map typName <$> allConstrArgs (mkD @Y)

    -- Will print [["X"],["Y"]]
    print $ map typName <$> allConstrArgs (mkD @Z)
```

Note that you will need the following extensions for this to work: `ScopedTypeVariables, DeriveDataTypeable, GADTs, AllowAmbiguousTypes, TypeApplications`